# SQL JOIN replacing an unwanted column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I created a `JOIN` query to be able to access the `username` column from the `users` table where `t.user_id = u.id`.

Unfortunately, there is an issue since creating this query. Now when I try to use the `id` from the triggers table, my variable is picking up the `id` from the `users` table.

Does anyone see how I can fix this?

```
try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql_triggers = "
        SELECT
            t.*,
            u.id,
            u.username
        FROM
            triggers AS t
        LEFT JOIN
            users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id
    ";
    $triggers_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_triggers);
    $triggers_stmt->execute();
    $triggers_rows = $triggers_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $triggers_arr = array();
    foreach ($triggers_rows as $triggers_row) {
        $trigger_id = $triggers_row['id'];
        $trigger_title = $triggers_row['trigger_name'];
        $trigger_description = $triggers_row['description'];
        $trigger_setting = $triggers_row['setting'];
        $trigger_user = $triggers_row['user_id'];
        $trigger_username = $triggers_row['username'];
```

triggers = t

```
CREATE TABLE `triggers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `trigger_name` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `setting` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `placement` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date_changed` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

users = u

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
 `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
 `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c
```

Comment: [Why did you delete your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59218017/1415724) Paul? I posted a comment and figured you'd of gotten back to me.

Comment: Since both table have the same field name then you need to differentiate them. You could use u.id AS UID in the sql statement then reference UID in subsequent operations.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I didn't see your comment, sorry. I deleted it because someone closed it.

Comment: @jeff would I do that here? `t.*,
   u.id,`

Comment: @Paul Ok. I admit that it should have been reopened, which I was going to, given there'd be more information given. However, you did have exceptions on, so I couldn't see why it was closed so fast. Edit: you can still see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218017/update-query-running-but-not-updating-database#comment104652800_59218017) in there though. (OP and 10k+)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The JS/AJAX isn't the issue. I figured out why it was failing. The query was pulling the `users` table `id` field for the `triggers` table `id`. I only have two users and two triggers, so it was very easy to spot once I saw the `var_dump` values.

Comment: @Paul I'm glad to hear that you found the issue Paul :) *Cheers*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I appreciate it and your attempt to help. Sorry again for not seeing your comment. I still have to figure out how to make this query work though.

Comment: Should be able to change the select to `t.*,  u.id as uid,  u.username` and then `id` will be the triggers table ID.

Comment: @Paul No worries Paul. Did the duplicate used to close this one with help at all? If it doesn't, you could ping the person that closed it to reopen. If they fail to either reopen / respond, ping me back and I'll see what I can do. I just don't want any bad blood between the closer and myself.

Comment: @NigelRen Just gave that a shot with `SELECT
   t.*,
   u.id AS uid,
   u.username
  FROM
   triggers AS t
  LEFT JOIN
   users AS u ON t.user_id = uid` No luck. The query breaks.

Comment: You only change it in the list of columns to select - `t.user_id = uid` should stay as `t.user_id = u.id`

Comment: @NigelRen Awesome. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: @NigelRen Would it be worth everyone's while for you to reopen and post your own answer? I'd be glad to support it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Don't mind who posts - if Paul wants to post his final code, that's fine.

Comment: @NigelRen Ok. In order for Paul to do that, we'd have to reopen.

Comment: @Paul Please post your answer/solution. Nigel reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to modify the SQL to get the result I was looking for. The users `id` column was clashing with the triggers `id` column. As NigelRen pointed out, changing `u.id,` to `u.id AS uid,` solved this issue.

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    u.id AS uid,
    u.username
FROM
    triggers AS t
LEFT JOIN
    users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id
";
```